# Get a vertex with its label, properties and in/out vertices and their properties?

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

How can can find a vertex by `name` property and get:
  1. vertices (with label and properties) incident on the incoming edges to this vertex?
  2. vertices (with label and properties) incident on the outgoing edges to this vertex?
In a single query.

I am aware that `.both()` and `.otherV()` does this, and I can use `.valueMap()` and `.label()` to get the metadata and properties, but the result (response received from server) of `.both()` or `.otherV()` don't clearly indicate and identify what are the **incoming** vertices and what are the **outgoing** vertices.

To be able to distinguish between the two, I am calling:
 * `g.V().has('name', 'abcd').in().values('name')` for indegrees
 * `g.V().has('name', 'abcd').out().values('name')` for outdegrees
and
 * `g.V().has('name', 'abcd').union(label(),valueMap())` for metadata

to clearly know what response belongs to what set, specially in the indegrees and outdegrees case. But this is inefficient and results in 3 separate calls to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should use `project`:

```
g.V().has('name', 'josh').
  project('properties', 'out', 'in').
    by(valueMap().
        with(WithOptions.tokens)).
    by(out().values('name').fold()).
    by(__.in().values('name').fold())
```

example: https://gremlify.com/c8nm1j16033g

Comment: thanks @noam621. What does `.with(WithOptions.tokens)` do? My client errors out on that with: `SCRIPT EVALUATION ERROR - Response Message: No such property: WithOptions for class: Script112885)`

Comment: return the `id` and `label` and not just the properties. you can also use the deprecated `valueMap(true)` instead